# DHTMLX Grid - How to run onRowSelect event?

Tags: events, grid, dhtmlx

I've faced a little problem with dhtmlxGrid. When I use this:

myGrid.selectRow(someRowId);

the event attached still doesn't run

myGrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function(id){
. . . 
});

How can I make it works? Is it possible to simulate a click on the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to enable the second attribute of the selectRow() method:
myGrid.selectRow(rowIndex,true);

It will cause the onRowSelect event to occur.